# How to specify a range of files that can be included when compiling C++ code?

Tags: c++, security, gcc, include

I've been making an online judge system, and need to prevent users from damaging it, or including non-standard libraries - so I want to limit the files can be included in a specific range (e.g. `iostream` and STL only). Is there a compiler option or other way to get this done?

I found the `-include` option, but it just adds `#include <xxx>` to the code; the `-l` option seems useless too.

Comment: How are you going to guarantee that those `#include` files will not include files you do not want?  For example, many compilers include `<string>` by simply including `<iostream>`.  Also, how is a solution "damaging your system" if the solver comes up with perfectly valid, C++ way of solving the problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using a chroot jail or container to isolate the users from your host system?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For the first question: I only want to specify the files users can include directly. If other files are included indirectly, that's OK; For the second: besides the C++ standard library, users may include other libraries that comes with the compiler; they may also read files on the machine, etc.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm sorry that I didn't mention in the question - I also need to prevent them from including non-standard libraries.

Comment: My point is in a chroot jail or container you can remove any headers and libraries you want.

Comment: @drescherjm Sounds worth a try, thanks.

Comment: If you can banish <bits/stdc++.h> you may have a solution to a particularly stupid problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Actually I need to remove everything not in the C++ standard and even some in the standard, such as `<thread>`.